# Валидация полей формы ajax

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-validation

У меня есть форма с текстовым полем и двумя кнопками (Перва - отправляет сообщение, вторая - очищает текущий список). Пример работы показан по ссылке на [jsfeedle](https://jsfiddle.net/skvortsovg/xdoL60zt/4/). Форма отправляется, если я нажимаю на кнопку "Отправить", или когда нажимаю Enter, если нахожусь на поле ввода.

Я хочу проверять значение поля на непустоту. Сейчас если я нажимаю на Enter, то поле валидируется, но если нажимаю на кнопку - то нет.
Как мне добавить валидацию и при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить", и при нажатии на Enter?

Спасибо!

P.S. 
Приведу ниже часть кода, так как система не дает отправлять ссылку без сопровождения кодом.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="chatbot-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введи сообщение" name="messageText" id="messageText" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="chatbot-form-btn">Отправить</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="chatbot-form-btn-clear">Очистить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: И совершенно правильно система не даёт, потому что примеры должны быть целиком в тексте вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: самое легкое поменять `type` на `submit` и задать `input`ам аттрибут `required`. На `js` прописать `form.onsubmit` ваш аякс и вконце обработчика `return false` чтобы форма не отправлялась не по `ajax`e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Меняем `type="button"` на `type="submit"`

2) Убираем обработчик клика (либо с нутри его вытри `submit`)

```js
$(function() {

  $('#chatbot-form-btn-clear').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.mesgs').find('.msg_history').html('');
  });

  $('#chatbot-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $('#messageText').val();
    $(".msg_history").append('<div class="outgoing_msg"><div class="sent_msg question"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div>');
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-Csrf-Token': csrf_token
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ask",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        $('#messageText').val('');
        var answer = response.answer;
        const chatPanel = document.getElementById("chatPanel");
        $('.feedbackDiv').remove();
        $(".msg_history").append('<div class="incoming_msg">' +
          '<div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="static/chatbot_avatar.png"> </div>' +
          '<div class="received_msg">' +
          '<div class="received_withd_msg answer">' +
          '<p>' + answer + '</p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="feedbackDiv"> (Оценить ответ: ' +
          '<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="bad-ans-btn" onclick="AnswerFunc(this.id)">' +
          '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-border" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
          '</button>' +
          '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="good-ans-btn" onclick="AnswerFunc(this.id)">' +
          '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-border" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
          '</button>' +
          '</div>' +
          ') </div>' +
          '</div>');
        $(".msg_history").stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(".msg_history")[0].scrollHeight
        }, 1000);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
  <div class="inbox_msg">

    <div class="mesgs">
      <div class="msg_history">

      </div>
      <form action="" method="post" id="chatbot-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введи сообщение" name="messageText" id="messageText" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="chatbot-form-btn">Отправить</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="chatbot-form-btn-clear">Очистить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```